How include graphics image at origin in TikZ picture?
In a drawing program (Linearity Curve) I drew a closed curve southeast of the upper-left corner of the canvas and exported the result as shape.png. That canvas has coordinates (0,0) fixed at its upper-left corner (as is the case with many drawing apps).
How do I make that image appear at the origin, coordinates (0,0), of a TikZ picture, as in the following source?
The closed curve was created with dimensions roughly 4cm wide by 3cm hight.
But the closed curve is shown far to the northwest of even my 10 cm x 10 cm TikZ grid, as shown.
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
    \node(origin) at (0,0) {\includegraphics*{shape.png}};
    \draw[help lines,line width=0.5pt,gray] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


An image of the .png is shown below. A copy of the image file shape.png is available at: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0ce47PPCL2MmOay6UWe4DEDtw#shape

(Whatever the process to solve this, I want to be able to generalize it to other images created in the drawing program.)

Your image is centered, but its size is bigger than the closed curve. Test with example-image instead of shape.png. Remove all the white space around the curve in shape.png.

@jlab: How does one remove that white space? The drawing program is exporting to a letter-size image.

The simpler is to use an external software. See also this question. Anyway, your shape is relatively simple, you can try to draw it with tikz.

@jlab: As I said, I want to be able to generalize the process to other images, also drawn freehand in the graphics program. I'll include those in TikZ, read off coordinates, etc., to convert into TikZ code. (The point is that visualization while drawing is much simpler and more direct in an actual drawing program, which TikZ is not!)

I would use convert from ImageMagick: convert -trim shape.png shape.png.

You can clip and trim using \includegraphics, but you need to know the measurements precisely.  I use GIMP to crop images.

Also \includegraphics won't actually clip the image. It just won't show it. The whole thing will still be included in the PDF.

@jlab: ImageMagic's convert does handle the trimming nicely. Thank you for that! If you combine your comments into an answer, I can accept that happily.

The image is centered, but its size is bigger than the closed curve. You need to remove all the white space around the curve in shape.png.
The simpler is to use an external software. For example, with convert from ImageMagick:
convert -trim shape.png shape.png

A way to run convert directly from latex is described in this answer.
